# onTextChanged - value of before and count

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am using a TextWatcher for my Edittext. In the onTextChanged method happens something strange.

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    Log.i("onTextChanged", "Count: "+ count + " Before: " + before);
    if (before > count) {
        ... do something
    }
}
```

when I write somthing in the Edittext, I expect output in logcat like this:

Input: s

```
I/onTextChanged﹕ Count: 1 Before: 0
```

Input: so

```
I/onTextChanged﹕ Count: 2 Before: 1
```

Input: som

```
I/onTextChanged﹕ Count: 3 Before: 2
```

Input: som[space] //add a space here

```
I/onTextChanged﹕ Count: 4 Before: 3
```

**What I expect when remove space**

Input: som //remove space here

```
I/onTextChanged﹕ Count: 3 Before: 4
```

**But when removing the space my output says**

Input: som //remove space here

```
I/onTextChanged﹕ Count: 3 Before: 1
```

What happend here? Why is Before = 1 and not 4?

Comment: are you removing space twice?  but one space was added...

Comment: The first //remove space - is what I expect when I do it and the secound //remove space - is what really happens. I try to make it more clear and edit my question

Comment: I dont remove two spaces, I remove only one space. But my example shows first what I expect the output should look like and the secound shows what really the output look like

Comment: but when removing normal chars, it goes down Count: 2 Before: 3, next step Count: 1 Before: 2.... only when a space is involed it "breaks" - I am using Softwarekeyboard

Comment: then use your pc keyboard you will be surprised...

Comment: I dont develop a android app to use it with a pc-keyboard?!

Comment: ok,  so goto "language and input" settings and in keyboard settings set "show corrections suggestions" to "always hide" and run your app again,  you will now have no suggestions, the same as using pc keyboard

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76008/discussion-between-visores-and-pskink).